# Firmware recommendations

Tags: discussion, scope

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firmware):

> In electronic systems and computing, firmware[a] is a type of computer program that provides the low-level program control for the device's specific hardware.

Firmware is quite specific because quite often there is only one for a specific piece of hardware, and sometimes it can not even be changed.

Question: Are firmware recommendations on-topic?

- If no: Why?
- If yes: What should a good firmware recommendation question include?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that firmware recommendation questions should be **on-topic**.

Any firmware recommendation question must include:

- The full name of the hardware.
- Link to the hardware specification on the maker's official website, or if not available, to the best technical information page available for it.
- The name and version of the default firmware (shipped with the hardware)
- The reason why the default firmware does not satisfy your needs. For instance, it crashes when you perform action X, or it does not have feature Y, or it is not open source.

Comment: We should at least differentiate between "just asking for a download link" (e.g. "where to download XYZ FW v1.2.3") and questions on firmware alternatives. The former should be off-topic – the latter I can follow your reasoning (e.g. with Android custom ROMs in mind, or related to [Is recommending operating systems allowed on this site?](/questions/11/185))

Comment: Absolutely agree - there's no reason we should make a distinction.